# Show that $\{z_n\}$ converges $L$ if and only if $Re(z_n) $ converges to $Re(L)$ and $Im(z_n) $ converges to $Im(L)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $\{z_n\}$ converges $L$ if and only if $Re(z_n) $ converges to $Re(L)$ and $Im(z_n) $ converges to $Im(L)$

I proved that if $Re(z_n) $ converges to $Re(L)$ and $Im(z_n) $ converges to $Im(L)$ then $\{z_n\}$ converges $L$ .

But I'm bit confused with other implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
z_{n}-L&=\mbox{Re}(z_{n})+i \mbox{Im}(z_{n})-(\mbox{Re}(L)+i\mbox{Im}(L)) \\
&=\mbox{Re}(z_{n})-\mbox{Re}(L)+i \left(\mbox{Im}(z_{n})-\mbox{Im}(L) \right)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
|z_{n}-L|
&=\sqrt{(\mbox{Re}(z_{n})-\mbox{Re}(L))^{2}+ \left(\mbox{Im}(z_{n})-\mbox{Im}(L) \right)^{2}}\\
& \geq |\mbox{Re}(z_{n})-\mbox{Re}(L)|,|\mbox{Im}(z_{n})-\mbox{Im}(L)|
\end{align}
Therefore if $z_{n} \to L$ then $ |\mbox{Re}(z_{n})-\mbox{Re}(L)|,|\mbox{Im}(z_{n})-\mbox{Im}(L)| \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of the topology on $\Bbb{C}$ as the topology on $\Bbb{R}^2$. To prove the claim in $\Bbb{R}^2$, consider the projection functions $\pi_1,\pi_2:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ and use their continuity to show that $(x_n)\to L$ implies $(\pi_1 (x_n)) \to \pi_1(L)$ and $(\pi_2 (x_n)) \to \pi_2(L)$.